# verify heading text in css selector

Tags: groovy, css-selectors, geb

This is my xpath `"//div[@class='city']/h4[text()='Newyork']"`

`xpath`s I can use in `Geb` but I want to write similar expression in CSS or better Groovy-ish, Gebish locator.

I have tried

`.city>h4:'Newyork'`

`.city>h4:contains('Newyork')`

but none worked.

I have referred https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/362/a-way-to-match-on-text-using-css-locators

Comment: The linked question is about Selenium, not plain CSS. Plain CSS can't address text nodes. There was a proposal for `:contains`, but that wouldn't be able to handle text either. I'm afraid you're out of luck and you'll have to resort to giving the h4 a unique class or something.

Comment: That said, you're talking about Geb, which I'm not familiar with. Maybe there _is_ a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geb has an ability to further filter down the elements matched using a CSS selector by passing a map of element attributes to its methods together with that selector. It also introduces [a special attribute for matching text of a node](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#attribute-and-text-matching). Your selector would look like this:

```
$('div.city > h4', text: 'Newyork')
```

Please note that this works by fetching text for every matched element and checking it against the provided value, that is it does the work on the JVM side and not in the browser, which means that you want your css selector to be as specific as possible and match as little elements as possible otherwise the selector will be very slow.